# Apply PreAuthorize only to first service method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am exposing service methods trought controllers and the service interfaces have @PreAuthorize checks, however sometimes a service call another service and I would like to only check the condition of the first service.

For example:

```java
public interface UserService {
   @PreAuthorize(/*Condition A*/)
   public User getUser();
}
```

```java
public interface PermissionService {
   @PreAuthorize(/*Condition B*/)
   public User getPermission();
}
```

The UserService implementation call the PermissionService's method:

```java
public class PermissionServiceImpl implements PermissionService {

   public User getPermission() {
      // ...
      permissionService.getPermission();
      // ...
   }
}
```

Is it possible to only apply condition A when the UserService is called through its controller and Condition B when the PermissionService is called through its controller?

Comment: IMO `PreAuthorize` should be used in the controller since it should check the user before any code is executed. I would check conditions A and B in the controller where the services are called and only execute the service code if all conditions necessary for the given endpoint are met. Then I would not need to check any conditions in the services.

Comment: Yes, it is an option, but I would like to see first if it is possible at the service level

Comment: @Scorpioo590 *IMO PreAuthorize should be used in the controller since it should check the user before any code is executed.* Spring Security recommends it on service layer: *In practice we recommend that you use method security at your service layer*, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Scorpioo590](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7381844/), I had to move the pre authorize checks to the Controller layer